# Which docker image is the official MySQL image?

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerhub, docker-image

I am trying to install MySQL in Docker.

When I searched for a MySQL image in Docker Hub, it gave me [`mysql`](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/). Which says it is "official" release.

But when I went to the MySQL website, [it says](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.7/en/docker-mysql-getting-started.html) that [`mysql/mysql-server`](https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/) is the official image.

I am a bit confused which is the official and which one I should use. Of course I **can** use either but which one **should** I use if I am concerned about using the official image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`mysql`](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) is officially supported by Docker.

[`mysql/mysql-server`](https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/) is officially supported by MySQL.

It is your choice which organization you want to rely on for updates, support, etc.