# Which is standard docker image for Antlr/Antlr4?

Tags: docker, parsing, antlr, antlr4, docker-image

I tried searching docker hub to find for antlr4 Images. As far I know, we don't have any official image as of now for `antlr` on dockerhub. Does anyone know, which is most suitable and standard image, preferable for JavaScript Parser related works?

I saw couple of image suggestions with individual account, but not sure which is reliable and robust enough.

Please don't suggest the general suggestions like, one with most downloads etc. is better. Please suggest if you have used or any other valid point you have.

Comment: Please read this before you try to become cool: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions. Please read all three bullet points and verify yourself. (**This question is neither unclear, nor already answered to similar question, nor off-topic**)

Comment: **If you are about to vote to close my question**, please read above comment and visit this question as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53414726/which-docker-image-is-the-official-mysql-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANTLR has a repo for docker image on Github:

> This Docker image wraps current version of ANTLR4 inclusive Java
> runtime environment so it can be executed as transparent command line
> tool even on machines without installed Java.

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/docker

Comment: Oh, Great, Thanks. Now we can definitely build image as suggested in readme (for others). Additionally, want to ask, why it is not there on docker-hub, OR can we somehow do so ( publish it there as official version) as community or raise as issue somewhere?

Comment: That is a good question. Write a message on github to the publisher imho.